# taking photo and saving it in to photo album

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i use this code for taking a photo:

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
} else {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

and i want to know how i can save this photo that i take to the photo album.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html), use:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()
```

Usage:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage, nil, nil, nil);
```